# How do I show the File Save Dialog Box for a Blobstore image?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a key to an image saved in the Blobstore. I want the user to be able to click on a button and save the image locally. The sample in the Blobstore documentation does this fine. Their code is:

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info,save_as=True)
```

But I want to use ajax. I do a GET with "/server/... the key..." and I get back the data in a form "GIF89a... image data...". Instead of putting up the Open/Save dialog, I get the data. There must be something about ajax and html I don't understand. How do I show the Open/Save dialog? I am new to Web programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't understand ajax. Ajax returns data. It doesn't render a page. I was using ajax to send "/server/...blob key...".  All I needed to do was:

```
windows.location = "/server/...blob key..."
```

and then I got the Save/Open dialog box.